# Leaflet divIcons set behind polygon features

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a polygon layer in my leaflet map (a geoJson layer):

```
var PolygonLayer = L.geoJson(json, {
style: polygon_style});
```

With this layer I have `DivIcon` labels enabled based on basic attributes:

```
var label = L.marker(polygonCenter, {
            icon: L.divIcon({
                className: 'label',
                html: '<div>' + label + '</div>'
            }),
        }).addTo(map);
```

I also have some highlight styling for mouseovers and click events.
If possible I would like to have these divIcon labels set *behind* the polygons, so that mouseover and pointing functions will not be inhibited.
I have tried setting the marker's zIndexOffset and the DivIcon's size to [0,0], but nothing has worked.  Is there any way of setting the polygons in front of the labels?

Answer (score 1):

In leaflet the z-index of the panes is set automatically.

I believe it is:

- popup pane
- marker pane
- overlay pane
- tile pane

from top to bottom

the overlay pane is where your polygon layer is. if you adjust the z-index of the marker pane to be behind the overlay pane then your markers should show up behind your polygons.

see this codepen for an example.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKvZZa

css:

```css
#map{width:400px;height:400px;}
.label{background-color:white;}
.leaflet-marker-pane{
  z-index:2
}
```

javascript:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
var accessToken='insert your mapbox access token here';
var mapboxTiles = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=' + accessToken, {
    attribution: '<a href="http://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Feedback</a>'
});

mapboxTiles.addTo(map);
var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map)

var myIcon = L.divIcon({
  iconSize: [70, 20],
  iconAnchor: [35, 10],
  className: 'label',
  html: '<div>' + 'test label' + '</div>'
})

L.marker([51.508, -0.11], {
    icon: myIcon
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Each geojson layer I add to the map can be re-ordered. Can I add points to the geojson layer somehow? Looking for an answer to this (more specific) question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34791059/482425

Comment: I can take a look at your other question separately. Do you need clarification on my answer to this question? I'm not sure if your comment is about this question or the one you linked to.

Comment: No sir - you appear to have answered this, if you have an answer to that other one as well, I'd be super obliged.

Comment: Apparently I can't approve the bounty for another 22 hours?